# Meaning of "havre de vie"

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

[havre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/havre#French) itself translates to haven, but I doubt the sentence below literally refers to "haven of life":

> Nous étions très surpris que ce **havre de vie** presque éternelle se trouve précisément à Okinawa, où 200000 innocents perdirent la vie à la fin de la Seconde Guerre mondiale.

Is this an expression that refers to something more precise?

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/havre B

Answer (score 2):

*Havre de vie* is a bit like "sanctuary of life".

A similar French expression is *havre de paix*.

Comment: I had to look for "in sort" meaning. [It seems very outdated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_sort)

Comment: @LaurentS. yes it's true that this expression is old, first I wanted in a such way but I thought in sort would be maybe reintroduced as it is shorter :)

Answer (score 2):

The original meaning of "havre" is indeed a haven, a harbour. By extension, it takes in French the meaning of place of refuge or place of comfort. This is used to characterize a location where one feels safe and well. With this meanng, it has also, as I understand it, an overtone of remoteness.